# Get Response after jquery post

Tags: python, jquery, post, request

i have the following Post request

```
var test=$.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "cgi-bin/test.py",
                async: true,
                data: { params: JSON.stringify(domain) }
            });
```

that is running a python script that prints some lines. 
If i look at the object with the console on my browser i can see the response text but i cant use it with test.responseText and im getting undefined back and if i iterate over the object there is no response text.
So how can i get the responsetext of that request.

It does work with a synchron request but i want it to work with an asynchnos request too.

Comment: jquery ajax is async by default (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). Have you tried retrieving the data in a success callback?

Comment: use `test.done(function(response){...do stuff with response...})`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the success callback

```
var test;

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "cgi-bin/test.py",
    async: true,
    data: {
        params: JSON.stringify(domain)
    },
    success: function(response) {
        test = response;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply do:

```
$.post("cgi-bin/test.py", data: {params: JSON.stringify(domain) }, function(result) {
  console.log(result); 
});
```

Synchronous AJAX request are not supported anymore in jQuery since 1.8 version, if I'm not wrong about the version.